# Machine Code: How many Read and/or Write cycles are involved in the Fetch and Execute cycles of the following instructions execution?

Tags: machine-code

Okay, I'm going through past exam questions for a module, Computer Architecture, and I've come across the following question and I have no idea how to do it? If anyone can tell/show me how I would answer this or send me a link where I could learn how to answer this type of question that would be ideal. Thanks.

Q: How many Read and/or Write cycles are involved in the Fetch and Execute cycles of the 
   following instructions execution of the following :

a) LDA B $10EF corresponding machine code A6 10 EF, Extended addressing.

b) LDA B #$ 3B corresponding machine code C6 3B, Immediate addressing.

c) STA B $6020 corresponding machine code 57 60 20, Extended addressing.

Comment: You need to tell us the machine this is for.

Comment: Mein Gott, that looks like 6502, made famous in the Apple ][ and as the Terminator's humourous response selection circuitry :-)

Comment: I don't know. That's all it says for the question. It doesn't specify.

Comment: assume an 8 bit data bus (so one cycle per 8 bits) and count up the number of reads for the fetch, then what does the operation do, and how many cycles are required for that.  What part dont you understand?

Comment: This is meant to run on a [Terminator](http://www.pagetable.com/docs/terminator/01-23-13.jpg).

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand any of it.

Comment: It looks like 6502, but the opcodes are wrong. For example, the first instruction would be AD, not A6. I assume it's some derivative. Full 6502 opcodes and the cycles they require are at http://www.obelisk.demon.co.uk among other places. If I ignored the opcodes, the instructions are 4, 2, and 4 cycles, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't appear to be 6809 either.

Comment: IIRC "immediate addressing" means : the value is embedded in the instruction stream ?

Comment: @wildplasser Not sure what you mean by that, but my understanding of that means: use the specified value, rather than referring to a memory location. LDA #$3B means "Put value 3B in the accumulator (register A)."

Comment: @paxdiablo I wonder whether the instructions are for a theoretical machine described in the class materials, rather than something real-world.

Comment: For 6502 "A6" is LDX from zero-page. It is a two-byte instruction. Maybe this is for a 6800 ?

Comment: No, not the 680x series either. 6800 ldaa and staa has different encodings as does the 6809. It _could_ be a mythical CPU but then you're going to need the course notes for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Without the information regarding which CPU it is, all we can give is general advice on how to  work it out.

Those opcodes look like rather simple ones from the early days of the PC industry but they don't match the more popular chips of that time frame.

The basic approach would be to look up the instructions in the CPU reference/guide and it would *tell* you what read and write cycles would occur for a given instruction/addressing-mode combination.

For example, immediate addressing is usually just the extraction of a value at or near the program counter (PC) so would involve a simple read.

Extended addressing depends, of course, on what they mean by extended. It may be a single de-reference which would involve reading a word at or near the PC followed by the use of *that* value to read another. Or it may be *two* levels of indirection. Or their definition of extended could be some bizarre combination of indexed, based and indirect addressing combined, which would result in even more cycles.

Without the chip specs, it's difficult to be certain.

My advice is to comb through the course material (if available) to try and discern what CPU is being used, then look that up with your favourite search engine. It doesn't appear to be any of the usual suspects like Mostek 6502 and derivatives, the Motorola 680x series, or the TI chips.

The other thing you could try is to post all of the questions (or a link to them) up here, the extra information may provide a clue to the architecture in use.